# How to bundle json file to be read with require()? jspm mangles name to .json.js

Tags: javascript, json, jspm

I am exploring transitioning a browserify build to jspm.

browserify leaves code like:

```
require("defaults.json")
```

intact and finds the file "defaults.json" in the source directory and injects it into a structure that can be read by browserify's provided `require()`

jspm is instead providing an error:

```
jspm build main.js bundle.js
Building the bundle tree for main.js...

err  Error on fetch for defaults.json.js at file:///tmp/testapp/defaults.json.js
        Loading main.js
        Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/tmp/testapp/defaults.json.js'
         at Error (native)
```

Notice that:

- the error is ENOENT, no such file.
- because it adds ".js" onto the file name, becoming `defaults.json.js`, not `defaults.json` as appears in the `require` call.

I tried installing a json plugin for jspm with

```
jspm install json
```

That did not help, returning the same error on build.  Reinstalling with `rm -rf ./jspm_packages` and `jspm install` also return the same error on build.

How do I include the json file into the jspm build?

Comment: did you add the `!` after installing the json plugin?

Comment: I think I tried `require("defaults.json!")` and that did not work.  Is that it or is it `require("json!default.json")`....hmm.... neither of those two work.  I've seen the "!" in es6 module import examples, don't know if jspm provided require supports all of that or not.  What do you think?

Comment: @Patrick Thanks.  The magic format was `require("defaults.json!json")`

Comment: @Patrick Ahh... Now `require("defaults.json!")` works too.  Not sure why it did not work earlier.

Answer (score 0):

As @Patrick hinted:

```
require('defaults.json!')
```

works once the jspm json plugin is loaded with `jspm install json`.

```
require('defaults.app!json')
```

can be used in case the JSON-formatted file is not named with the `.json` extension.

[jspm Docs](http://jspm.io/docs/plugins.html) explain this clearly for ES6 `import` and apparently it is the same filename syntax in require.